# UIView's addMotionEffect: loses it's effect when on UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, core-animation, caanimation

You can reproduce the bug by downloading and running this code on a physical device: https://github.com/Hoya/RCCPeakableImageView

What is does is it's adding a parallax effect to Images via a UIImageView subclass. Try cloning, building the project, if you tilt/pan your phone the images will animate slightly to create a parallax effect.

The UIImageView subclass creates an internal UIImageView with a frame slightly bigger than itself, and adds UIInterpolatingMotionEffects via UIView's addMotionEffect: Pretty simple.

This works great when working with UIScrollView and UITableView, but for some reason when you scroll the UICollectionView, reused UICollectionViewCells will lose the motion effect. Note that interestingly the motion effect will start working again once you switch to either UIScrollView or UITableView demo and switch back to the UICollectionView demo.

Is there a work around for this?

## RCCCollectionViewController

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    RCCAppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
    RCCPeakableCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier
                                                                           forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.imageView setImage:appDelegate.images[indexPath.row]];
    [cell.imageView setPadding:CGPointMake(20.f, 20.f)];
    
    return cell;
}
```

## RCCPeakableCollectionViewCell

```
@interface RCCPeakableCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet RCCPeakableImageView *imageView;
@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue in your code:

```
[cell.imageView setImage:appDelegate.images[indexPath.row]];
[cell.imageView setPadding:CGPointMake(20.f, 20.f)];
```

Here, `setImage:` will add some motion effects on the image view, then `setPadding:` will add those again.

I have done some modification on `RCCPeakableImageView` class, move the adding the motion effects code to `layoutSubviews`, and it works fine on reused UICollectionViewCell. Following is the updated code:

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
{
  // Store image
  self.RCC_imageView.image = image;

  [self setNeedsLayout];
}

- (void)setPadding:(CGPoint)padding
{
  // Store padding value
  _padding = padding;

  [self setNeedsLayout];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
  [super layoutSubviews];

  // Remove exising motion effects
  for (UIMotionEffect *effect in [self.RCC_imageView motionEffects]) {
    [self.RCC_imageView removeMotionEffect:effect];
  }

  // Add motion effects if there is any image.
  UIImage *image = self.RCC_imageView.image;
  if (image) {
    // code that add motion effects
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: brilliant "psychic solution" @Tony